# List of proofs of non-trivial theorems which were unnoticed to be wrong for at least a few years

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history, examples-counterexamples, big-list

For example, the Weber's proof of [Kronecker–Weber theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem).
I would like to know such proofs.
It seems to be important for me to remember that a widely accepted proof might be wrong.

Comment: Can we ask that answers in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/879/ not be repeated here?  (Unfortunately, that probably won't work.)

Comment: I. R. Shafarevich, Construction of fields of algebraic numbers with given solvable Galois group (1954)
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25242/where-can-i-find-the-paper-by-shafarevich-on-the-result-of-the-realization-of-so

Comment: Pontryagin proved that $\pi_{n+2}(\mathbb{S}^n) = 0$ in 1938. However, he and G.W. Whiteheand corrected it in 1950 independently.

Answer (score 14):

There are many variations on this theme in MathOverflow.

[Widely accepted mathematical results that were later shown wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-wrong)

[Failures that lead eventually to new mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77425/failures-that-lead-eventually-to-new-mathematics)

[Most interesting mathematics mistake](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/879/most-interesting-mathematics-mistake)

[How to refer to a theorem that you have shown to be wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126609/how-to-refer-to-a-theorem-that-you-have-shown-to-be-wrong)

[What are some correct results discovered with incorrect or no proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27749/what-are-some-correct-results-discovered-with-incorrect-or-no-proofs)

[Examples where physical heuristics led to incorrect answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30149/examples-where-physical-heuristics-led-to-incorrect-answers)

[Oldest bug in computer algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16365/oldest-bug-in-computer-algebra-system)

[Retracted mathematics papers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119254/retracted-mathematics-papers)

[What mistakes did the italian algebraic geometers actually make](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19420/what-mistakes-did-the-italian-algebraic-geometers-actually-make)

[Italian school of algebraic geometry and rigorous proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17352/italian-school-of-algebraic-geometry-and-rigorous-proofs)

[Can a mathematical definition be wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31358/can-a-mathematical-definition-be-wrong)

[Mathematicians whose works were criticized by contemporaries but became widely accepted later](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121565/mathematicians-whose-works-were-criticized-by-contemporaries-but-became-widely-a)

[What are examples of theorem which were once valid then became invalid as standard definitions shifted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67879/what-are-examples-of-theorems-which-were-once-valid-then-became-invalid-as)

[Have we ever lost any mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96510/have-we-ever-lost-any-mathematics)

[Examples of conjectures that were widely believed to be true but later proved false](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95865/examples-of-conjectures-that-were-widely-believed-to-be-true-but-later-proved-false)

[Statements which were given as axioms which later turned out to be false](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116744/statements-which-were-given-as-axioms-which-later-turned-out-to-be-false)

and for good measure

[Smith-Minkowski-Siegel mass formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Minkowski%E2%80%93Siegel_mass_formula)

[Grunwald-Wang theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem)

[Polygons Flip Finitely: Flaws and a Fix](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/Papers/Nagy.fix.pdf)

Comment: a good list here with fresh material: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139503/in-the-history-of-mathematics-has-there-ever-been-a-mistake

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_incomplete_proofs

Comment: (accumulating material in comments for the next edit)